# Dynamically Rename Field in Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

So given the following code

```
{
    fieldName: foo
    data: large json object
}
```

I would like to send the object

```
{
     foo_data: large json object
}
```

I tried using the mutate rename

```
{
     rename => { "data" => "%{fieldName}_data" }
}
```

But I just ended up with %{fieldName}_data. Does anyone know of a filter that will allow me to do this?

Also I thought about using add_field/drop_field but could this cause a performance issue since data contains a large json object?

**UPDATE**

As Val mentioned I just mistyped the field name I was trying to use

Comment: Which version of Logstash are you using? and are you certain that your event contains a field called `fieldName`?

Comment: Logstash 5.4 and yes.

Comment: Strike that no, just ended up being a typing mistake. Thanks Val

Comment: Good you figured it out!

Comment: Just some trivial check (sorry for being obvious), if you are defining a new field "fieldName", is the rename filter called after its definition? Have you checked for typos? The mutate filter is called inside the "filter" section? (not input or output). This code should work, according to the documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-rename

Comment: Sorry for the post, it looks like you have solved in the meanwhile. I was too slow to write the comment :)